# How to implement a power function using variable templates

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to understand variable templates. I tried the code below, which performs an integer power. Why does clang++ return `0` instead of `8`?

```
#include <iostream>

template<int n, int e>
int r = n * r<n, e - 1>;

template<int n>
int r<n, 0> = 1;

int main() {
    std::cout << r<2, 3>;
}
```

Comment: All versions of clang do this!

Comment: fyi - clang: 0 gcc:: 8 - live - https://godbolt.org/z/5v3hTdKfT

Comment: Can templates be *that* recursive?

Comment: I wonder if clang  considers `r<n, e - 1>` value as `0` because it is being used before it was initialized with a value but since it has static storage it gets zero initialized.

Comment: Not the first issue I got with clang 15 and templates. It works with clang (trunk): https://godbolt.org/z/bGc67s9vv

Comment: fyi2: `std::cout << r<2, 0>;` outputs `1` from both compilers.

Comment: fyi3: adding `const` starts working (no idea why) - live - https://godbolt.org/z/xxdfvcjGf

Comment: @RichardCritten, another data point https://godbolt.org/z/bT41K8PeT

Comment: Hint: when is `r<n, e>` initialized for various `n` and `e` values (you likely have an initialization order fiasco - that's why `constexpr` works).

Comment: it doesn;t make sense for this to be mutable, otherwise you can assign any value to specific instances of `r`.

Comment: Consider also this: https://godbolt.org/z/6nYfe4EKa . Quoting https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template : "Unless a variable template was explicitly specialized or explicitly instantiated, it is implicitly instantiated when a specialization of the variable template is referenced in a context that requires a variable definition to exist or if the existence of the definition affects the semantics of the program, i.e. if the variable is needed for constant evaluation by an expression (the definition may be not used)."

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`r<2, 3>` is initialized with `2 * r<2, 2>`.

The type of `r<2, 2>` is `int`, which is a non-const integral type, and `r<2, 2>` is not marked `constexpr`. Therefore `r<2, 2>` is not *usable in constant expressions*. The lifetime of `r<2, 2>` also doesn't start during initialization of `r<2, 3>`, so none of the exceptions in [[expr.const]/5.8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#5.8) apply and the initialization of `r<2, 3>` is not a constant expression.

This means that `r<2, 3>` is not constant-initialized and may have dynamic initialization. If it has dynamic initialization, then it has *unordered dynamic initialization*, because it is a specialization of a template.

The same reasoning applies to `r<2, 2>` and it may also have unordered dynamic initialization.

The order in which variables with unordered dynamic initialization are initialized is completely indeterminate. Before any dynamic initialization is done all variables with dynamic initialization are zero-initialized. Therefore it is possible that `r<2, 3>` is initialized before `r<2, 2>`, in which case the former is initialized with `2 * 0`.

On the other hand `r<2, 0>`'s initialization is a constant expression and therefore it never has dynamic initialization. As a consequence `r<2, 1>` should always be initialized to `2`, never to `0`. (And Clang gives the expected value when using `r<2, 1>` instead of `r<2, 3>` in your `main`.)

If you mark the variables `constexpr` then all specializations become usable in constant expressions and constant-initialized and it should work as expected.

See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Non-local_variables) for a reference on how non-local variables are initialized including the behavior I describe above.

---

While you should use `constexpr`, `const` is probably also enough in this specific instance (as it seems to be on Clang), since for historical reasons a variable of `const` integral type is also *usable in constant expressions* if it has a preceding initialization with a constant expression. However there are some open questions on the point of instantiation of variable template specializations (see [CWG 1845](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1845.html)) and on what exactly "preceding" is supposed to mean (see [CWG 2186](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2186.html)).

---

One could also argue that your program has undefined behavior because (dynamic) initialization of `r<2, 2>` may not be done yet when used in `r<2, 3>` initialization. The standard is bit unclear on this, as argued [here](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/4802), but I do not think that this is intended interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

I think runtime template variables can't be *that* recursive.
The evaluation needs to be sequential.

(It works in GCC by chance probably. This is probably UB and clang is dereferencing an uninitialized value.)

It works with `constexpr`, which anyway is what you probably want.

```
#include <iostream>

template<int n, int e>
constexpr int r = n * r<n, e - 1>;

template<int n>
constexpr int r<n, 0> = 1;

int main() {
    std::cout << r<2, 3>;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xGhhqf8rd

Comment: FWIW clang trunk does give the expected results for the OP's code.  Also, why do you say runtime?  Nothing in the OP's code requires the initialization to be done at run time.

Comment: @alfC can you explain why `constexpr` makes the code valid?

Comment: @cmutex, not really, I **guess** `constexpr` can do the leap/work of evaluating the initialization in any order necessary  (like template instantiation). While at runtime it cannot (or doesn't need to).